# T.test on a small set of data from a large set

Tags: r, dataset, sample

we compare the average (or mean) of one group against the set average (or mean). This set average can be any theoretical value (or it can be the population mean).

I am trying to compute the average mean of a small group of 300 observations against 1500 observations using one sided t.test.Is this approach correct? If not is there an alternative to this?

```
    head(data$BMI)
    attach(data)
    tester<-mean(BMI)
    table(BMI)
    set.seed(123)
    sampler<-sample(min(BMI):max(BMI),300,replace = TRUE)
    mean(sampler)
    t.test(sampler,tester)
```

The last line of the code yield-
    Error in t.test.default(sampler, tester) : not enough 'y' observations

Comment: I think you actually should focus on the statistical question but that is off-topic here, so let's focus on the programming issue. A one-sample t-test would be `t.test(sampler, mu = tester)`. A "one sided t.test" is something different, i.e., the allternative hypothesis is not mean != mu but mean < mu or alternatively mean > mu.

Comment: I think that for t.test as a parametric test both groups need to be equal. In addition to this the distribution should be normal or at least simillar between them. Also don't forhet about homogenity of variance. In this case I'll recommend to use non-parametric `wilcox.test()`

Comment: @Adamm, for performing a t.test on two unpaired data, you don't need to have equal size. However, you're right that the normality of the distribution of each group need to be tested first (using a `shapiro.test` for example) even if you can called the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) that assume than for sample size bigger than 30 you should tend toward a normal distribution

Answer (score 0):

For testing your sample in t.test, you can do:

```r
d <- rnorm(1500,mean = 3, sd = 1)
s <- sample(d,300)
```

Then, test for the normality of `d` and `s`:

```r
> shapiro.test(d)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  d
W = 0.9993, p-value = 0.8734

> shapiro.test(s)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  s
W = 0.99202, p-value = 0.1065
```

Here the test is superior to 0.05, so you could consider that both `d` and `s` are normally distributed. So, you can test for t.test:

```r
> t.test(d,s)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  d and s
t = 0.32389, df = 444.25, p-value = 0.7462
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.09790144  0.13653776
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2.969257  2.949939
```

Comment: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2501/11849)

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for sharing this discussion. Really interesting reading. I'm also not that confident in Normality test. I usually used them not to decide if my data are normally distributed but rather as a complementary information.